# Коментарии в GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

В Gson имеется такая возможность как полный контроль над этапом Serializer и Deserializer объекта.

```
public class SimpleClassSerializer implements JsonSerializer<SimpleClass>, JsonDeserializer<SimpleClass>
```

После реализации данных интерфейсов от нас требуется реализовать сериализацию и десериализацию. Вопрос, можно ли в моменте сериализации данных написать комментарий к тому или иному параметру? Я такой возможности не нашёл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Формат `JSON` [не поддерживает комментарии](https://stackoverflow.com/a/244858/3212712) согласно информации о стандарте по этим ссылкам: http://www.json.org, [RFC 4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt), [RFC 7159](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc7159.txt).

Единственное, что вы можете сделать - добавить новые поля в объекты и в них что-то написать:

```
{
   "_comment": "Тут ваш комментарий...",
   "example": {
      "title": "example"
   }
}
```